# How do you define volume for gases?

Tags: thermodynamics, atoms, molecules, gas, volume

Straight forward question. If atoms forming a gas float far from each other, how can we assign a volume to it? if it is in a container, perhaps we'd say the atoms, or molecules, reach every corner and thus its volume is the container's, but what about when it's in the air (think vacuum)? Do we consider a closed surface that contains the outermost atoms and the volume it encloses is the gas's?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Gases in the air? Air is a gas, consists of molecules.

Comment: *If atoms forming a gas float far from each other, how can we assign a volume to it?* The gas mingles with the air around it because of diffusion. W/o sharp boundaries no volume can be defined.

Comment: @Pieter think vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

If you are considering a gas/partial vacuum that is not confined in a well-defined 'container', you would presumably want use *specific volume* (aka inverse density) instead. I.e. consider the amount of volume occupied per unit mass of the substance.

Comment: is there a reference distance between two immediate molecules (consider they're at the edge of the "volume") such that if surpassed one of them is no longer considered part of the volume?

Comment: There is the [Knudsen Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knudsen_number), which compares the mean free path of molecules to a representative distance scale. As it approaches 1, the continuum hypothesis breaks down and so molecules can no longer be considered to be part of a continuum.

Answer (score 1):

Because gas is compressible, you must specify its *pressure* along with the volume it happens to occupy in order to properly define its *state*. And since heating a gas causes its pressure to increase, a complete description of any gas will necessarily include calling out its *temperature* as well.

Since more gas atoms in a fixed volume will exert more pressure on the thing containing them, a complete account of the state of a parcel of gas also includes a count of how many atoms of it there are inside that container.

This is summarized in an equation called the *ideal gas law*:

pressure x volume = number of atoms x a constant x temperature.

Comment: I can't see how this relates to a gas in a vacuum. Can you please put me on track?

Comment: it does not relate to gas in a vacuum. I guess I do not understand then what exactly you are asking, because a gas *cannot* have a "pressure" in a vacuum, because the pressure in a vacuum is identically zero.